# ¿Cómo hacer zoom-in o zoom-out en una gráfica en visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

Quiero poder aumentar y reducir la escala de la imagen en una gráfica de puntos, splines, en vb. ¿Existe alguna herramienta para hacerlo fácilmente?
La gráfica en concreto es esta: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado una solución, por si alguien encuentra este post en busca de ayuda. Lo que tienes que hacer es añadir este private sub a tu código:

No funciona a la perfección, pero está bastante bien.

```
 Private Sub chart1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseWheel
    With Chart1
        If (e.Delta < 0) Then
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset()
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset()
        End If

        If (e.Delta > 0) Then
            Dim xMin As Double = .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum
            Dim xMax As Double = .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum
            Dim yMin As Double = .ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum
            Dim yMax As Double = .ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMaximum
            Dim posXStart As Double = (.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) _
                    - ((xMax - xMin) _
                    / 4))
            Dim posXFinish As Double = (.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) _
                    + ((xMax - xMin) _
                    / 4))
            Dim posYStart As Double = (.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) _
                    - ((yMax - yMin) _
                    / 4))
            Dim posYFinish As Double = (.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) _
                    + ((yMax - yMin) _
                    / 4))
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish)
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```